# How to apply joins on different context files

Tags: c#, database, linq, join, ef-core-3.1

```cs
var InsertionId = 
    _DvContext.DvInsertionOrder
        .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.KiteDealId, x.KiteCampaignId, x.CampaignId })
        .ToList();

var camapignId = _kcdbContext.KiteLineitems
                 .Select(x=> new { x.CampaignId, x.Id }).ToList();
```

I have these two queries how I apply join on it. In where condition I want to match campaignID.

Comment: Cannot join different contexts with EF. Make two separate requests to both databases and map them in the code

Comment: map it using Where clause or other idea ?

Comment: Show the query you want please

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre]. We can't help you without knowing what you did exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot join two dbcontext on one request. You must store them in memory.

By executing ToList(), the EF/SQL query is executed and it is now in memory. So you could try now something like this

```
//implement your where and select, etc.
var objectsFromContext1 = _dbContext1.Entities.(where,select to DTOObject1).ToList();

//implement your where and select, etc.
var objectsFromContext2 = _dbContext2.Entities.(where,select to DTOObject2).ToList();

var joined = objectsFromContext1.Join(objectsFromContext2 ,
                      db1 => db1.PropertyToBeBasisOfJoined, 
                      db2 => db2.PropertyToBeBasisOfJoined, 
                      (db1 , db2 ) => new MyJoinedClass
                      {
                         //properties
                      }).ToList();
```